# Combine output of 2 unrelated queries

Tags: sql-server

I need to execute the 2 queries at one shot and generate the result in one combined output. Both the queries return only 1 row

Query 1:

```
SELECT city, state FROM "Table1" WHERE Id = '123'
```

Query 2:

```
select count(*) as colCount from "Table2" where name = "xyz"
```

Output format: `city, state, colCount`

Comment: Do you want two rows as result or one?

Comment: There will be only one column for second query every time?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, only one row as result

Comment: @ShaikhFarooque, yes only one column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a sub-query:

```
SELECT city, state, 
       colCount = (SELECT count(*)
                   FROM Table2 
                   WHERE name = "xyz")
FROM Table1 
WHERE Id = '123'
```

The sub-query cannot return more than one row. But that should not be the case as stated. You could use `TOP 1` to ensure it, but if it's exceptional i would prefer an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Following query will work for you:

```
SELECT city, state, 
       colCount = (SELECT count(*)
                   FROM Table2 
                   WHERE name = "xyz") as colCount
FROM Table1 
WHERE Id = '123'
```